# Qt 5.1 Compiler error

Tags: qt, compiler-construction

I have Qt 5.1. Used it for a couple of times. Compiling worked before just how it should. But suddenly it gives me this error (see below) if I want to compile. Where can I install the compiler. Because it looks like I dont have a compiler anymore.

`:-1: error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.`

Currently my kit:
[image]

Comment: Well, what compiler is your kit set to use? (Tools->Options->Build and Run->Kits). What compiler do you want to use (i.e. what compiler do you have installed)?

Comment: If something messed your compiler configuration, recovering it manually might get difficult. From your other questions I see that you seem to use MSVC. First, haven't you uninstalled MSVC (or upgraded it to the newest, I'm not sure if QtCreator supports it)? Qt creator doesn't come with MSVC, you must install it separately. you should also check if Qt's version matches MSVC's version. If that doesn't help you can always use Qt' maintenance tool to instal MinGW instead - it should install it and set everything up for you - but it will cause changes in compilation diagnostics.

Comment: @j_kubik you are right I uninstalled MSVC. But I thought it wouldn't have any impact on Qt Creator. But then I reinstalled it. And still got the problem

Comment: @Cameron check the question, ive updated the Q with a picture of my kit

Comment: @Sven: If you've uninstalled MSVC (which Qt was using), then re-installed it, unless everything is exactly the same as before, it's likely not to work without some manual configuration. You probably need to add/edit an entry under the "Compilers" tab to match the MSVC installation, then fix the kit to use that compiler.

Comment: Qt could have simply mark this compiler as unavailable and keep to it even when updated - my advice: If you installed MSVC again, first look if you can see it on the compiler tab under auto-detected. If you do, then try just adding a new kit with the right options. If you don't, the there is probably something wrong with your MSVC installation.

Comment: @j_kubik I've tried re-installing both Qt Creator and MSVC. Maybe it's because I've downloaded the wrong MSVC? Which download would you recommend for me to download?

Comment: Qt 5.1.1 should work with 2010 (32bit) or 2012 (32 and 64 bit)version of MSVC. It doesn't seem to support msvc 2013 yet, so this is not an option now. I don't have much experience with different versions of msvc (I use mingw mostly), but I would expect that express version of MSVC is already enough: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673 . Not that you should also have matching Qt-libraries installed - make sure that you run qt mainterance tool and install qt with libraries for your version of msvc.